# Как импортировать csv-файлы в Google Colab и из него?

Tags: python

Например, когда я использую `df.to_csv('file.csv')`, Google Colab проводит эту операцию, но где расположен созданный файл, я не знаю.
Аналогично, куда нужно поместить мой csv-файл, чтобы затем загрузить его в Notebook с помощью `pandas.read_csv()`?

Comment: Попробуйте так: pd.read_csv(“/content/drive/My Drive/file.csv”) или просто pd.read_csv(“file.csv”)

Comment: @MaxU не работает, в том числе если добавлять/не добавлять в адрес папку Colab Notebook, где лежит сам код, класть в эту папку/в корень гугл диска csv-файл